# Laravel: how to check if a user is logged with oauth?

Tags: authentication, oauth, laravel-4

I'm implementing social login with oauth using the package [oauth-4-laravel](https://github.com/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel) in my laravel application.
Following the instructions of the package I'm able to connect with facebook or with google.
Now I don't want to store user data but still I want a user to access a page only if legged with facebook or google.
I have to check if a user is logged with oauth in a route filter. Something like this

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (!OAuth::check()) return Redirect::guest('login');
});
```

How do I do that? Or should I use another method?

Answer (score 0):

Typically even when you use OAuth as authentication method, your application will still have to store user_id or name, and their email isn't it? If so, you can still apply laravel authentication like so:

```
//After the OAuth authentication
$user = User::where('email', $email)->firstOrFail(); //$email is the email returned from OAuth

//without acessing DB
$user = new User();
$user->email = $email; //this is an eg, can be replace with whatever user's properties you have.

Auth::login($user); //login the user using laravel

//To logout user manually
Auth::logout();

//In your filters.php
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) 
        return Redirect::guest('login');
});
```

Comment: So can't I do it without storing user data?

Comment: Well I would have to question your intention of not storing any user data, but still wants them to authenticate before accessing the page, why go through the trouble of authentication when you don't need any of the user's data?

Comment: I've updated the solution to use Laravel Auth without storing the user's data in the DB, but you'll still need a User model.

Comment: Uhm I think you're right. Avoid storing user data is pointless.
Anyway I was wondering if I could check when a user logged in, let's say, with facebook since oauth stores this user somewhere BEFORE i log in that user with L'aravel's auth.
I tried checking the session but there's nothing related to oauth there...

Comment: Well, if you use the filter above you could've done that, when the user come the first time, the filter will redirect to login page, in which you will perform OAuth and after that login with laravel auth, then the user would not need to be login again until the session expired or manually logged out.